# JavaScript Regex Replacement with Reference

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling a little bit with a JavaScript regex statement - and I can't quite see what's wrong. I've tested in online tools and they suggest it should work so I'm assuming there's something different between C# regex that I'm used to and JavaScript.

The string I'm working with is quite simple:

```
[a] + [b]
```

The regex match I'm trying to use is:

```
/[(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9])/]
```

I'm trying to replace the value with the following:

```
viewModel.$1.control.value()
```

Which should leave me with:

```
viewModel.a.control.value() + viewModel.b.control.value()
```

Unfortunately I'm always getting my inital value printed, suggesting my matching isn't working but I can't see why. The only obvious thing I tried was switching the escaping of the square brackets between forward and backslash.

Can anyone suggest what else might be wrong?

Comment: Yeah, escaping things with a forward slash is quite wrong and should actually be a syntax error. So if you could fix that first. Next, as far as I’m aware, JavaScript doesn’t support named captures… which should also be a syntax error. Have you checked your console at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no named groups in Javascript regex. Use this:

```
var s = '[a] + [b]';
repl = s.replace(/\[([a-zA-Z0-9])\]/g, 'viewModel.$1.control.value()');
//=> "viewModel.a.control.value() + viewModel.b.control.value()"
```

- Also you need to escape `[` and `]` in order to match them in a regex.

Comment: You should add that you fixed the escaping

Comment: I think you've just thrown something in that I've never seen before - how is the first parameter into s.replace a string?

Comment: Yes since code is using `$1` in replaced string: `'viewModel.$1.control.value()'` therefore whatever is captured in group #1 gets replaced in the string `'viewModel.$1.control.value()'` and final string becomes `'viewModel.a.control.value()'` OR `'viewModel.b.control.value()'`

Comment: Sorry - I understood that bit, just surprised you're regex string didn't have single or double quotation marks around it.

Comment: Oh regex string in Javastcript is enclosed in `/` and `/` OR else we could use `new RegExp` constrictor.